# Using MonthNo with null values?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a new column in my Power BI project like this:

[image]

However, I am running into difficulties because of the fact that my data set contains null values:

[image]

And as a result I get this error.

[image]

If I enter Month values in to my data for nulls the formula works e.g.:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on a workaround for this?

Here is how I have my table formatted in the Query editor:

With Null Values:
[image]

With No Null Values:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not use `MONTH('Table1'[Value])` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Start with I had data looking like this

[image: Starting Point]

On Query Editor, Right Click the Column "Value" and Duplicate it.

[image]

You will get something like this-

[image]

Now, click on the duplicated column header and change its name to MonthNumber.

Right Click on the Month Number Column and click on Change Type and Select Date

[image]

Once you have Selected Date, Right Click on the Column Again and Click on Transform, Select Month and Month Again.

[image]

So now you will have your MonthNumber.

Let me know, if this doesn't help.

[image]